# Windows store app, How to get the header value of gridview?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-store-apps, datatemplate

Here is the groupstyle of gridview in .xaml.

```
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="HeaderBtn" Click="HeaderButton_Click">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Key}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
             </GourpStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
```

The binding value key is the key of list.

Here is the button action.

```
    private void HeaderButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

When I click the button, how I get the text value of text block whose x:Name is "Title"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options :

The MVVM way would be to use an ICommand instead of the event and pass the value as the command parameter.

```
<Button x:Name="HeaderBtn" Command="{Binding HeaderCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Title}">
```

In the event Handler, you should be able to retrieve the data context of the button, and the value of title

```
private void HeaderButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
var button = (Button)sender;
var dataContext = (HeaderClass)button.DataContext;
var title = dataContext.Title; //here is your value
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solve the problem. But do you mean use an ICommand is recommended? why?